# Get the Id of a newly created entity in Entity Framework before it is saved to the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an endpoint which creates a new entity in the database. In the endpoint I need to update the database and then also create a new `Audit` entry to be added to an `Audits` table to log that this creation has happened.

The flow looks like this:

- Take the request model & map it to my DTO
- Get the parent entity from the database
- Add the new DTO to the parent entity
- Create a new `Audit` entity using the DTO
- Add the `Audit` to `Order.AuditEvents`
- Add Audit entry to the `Audits` table
- Update the database to reflect these changes

However, my issue is that I need the new, saved entity's `Id` to create the `Audit` entry. I get an `Internal Server Error` when I try something like the below:

```
// Turn `requestModel` into a `ProductEntity`
var product = _mapper.Map<Product>(requestModel);

order.AddProduct(product);

// this method creates an `AuditEvent` and saves it onto a collection of
// `Order.AuditEvents`
// the method needs the `product.Id` to log the event in the database
order.CreateAuditEvent(product);

// Save both the `Product` added to the `Order` as well as the `AuditEvents` on the `Order`
await _orderRepository.UpdateOrderAsync(order);
```

Due to this failing, I have to instead do something like the below:

```
var product = _mapper.Map<Product>(requestModel);

order.AddProduct(product);

// updated the database to include the newly added product
await _orderRepository.UpdateOrderAsync(order);

// get the newly created `Product` and pass it to `CreateAuditEvent`
var createdProduct= await productRepository.GetByIdAsync(order.Product.Id);
order.CreateAuditEvent(createdProduct);

// update the database AGAIN to save the `AuditEvents`
await _orderRepository.UpdateOrderAsync(order);
```

Is there a way for me to do this without calling `UpdateOrderAsync(order)` twice?

```
public Task UpdateOrderAsync(Order order)
{
    // nothing currently happens here with `order`
    return Context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to delete all this code, add or modify the objects you want and just make a single call to `SaveChanges` *once* at the very end. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a *multi-entity* Unit-of-Work that detects all changes to the objects it tracks and persists *all* of them in a single database transaction. That `UpdateOrder` can easily perform 42 DELETEs. `SaveChanges` effectivly commits the changes in the Unit-of-Work. When that happens, it fixes up any auto-generated IDs in all related objects. As for auditing, that's available through interceptors

Comment: The Interceptor docs show how to create a [SaveChanges interceptor specifically for auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-savechanges-interception-for-auditing). This is completely transparent to the rest of your code. The interceptor can write changes wherever you want. The example shows writing to the database

Comment: Well, the Note says: _"**This is not intended to be a robust auditing solution.** Rather it is a simplistic example used to demonstrate the features of interception."_ (emphasis by me) ... So I guess, you'll have to tweak that to make it more robust, still.

Answer (score 0):

In EF, references are everything. The first question is what does the product passed in actually represent? Typically when creating something like an order, the "product" isn't going to be treated as a new product row, but rather, an association to an existing product row.

Code like this:

```
// Turn `requestModel` into a `ProductEntity`
var product = _mapper.Map<Product>(requestModel);
```

... should not be used if the Product is intended to refer to an existing row in the database. Load it from the DbContext:

```
var product = _context.Products.Single(x => x.Id == requestModel.ProductId);
```

Check that order.AddProduct() isn't doing something that uses a different reference to a Product rather than the reference you initialized. If it does go to the DbContext or checks for duplicates (if this is editing an order vs. creating) etc. then you need to return the reference actually used.

Generic Repositories (OrderRepository, ProductRepository, etc.) are not your friends. They will make life difficult with working with EF leading to hiding potential problems and building inefficient code. EF already provides you with a Generic Repository in the form of the `DbSet<T>`, honestly just use it.

`Mapper.Map` should only be used when you want to insert a new entity, not reference an existing one. If you do intend to create a new Product row with this order then there may be an issue with your CreateAuditEvent method. EF manages references and their FK associations on save, so if you are creating an audit trying to just use FK properties:

```
var audit = new Audit 
{
   // .. populate values from this order..
   ProductId = product.Id 
}
AuditEvents.Add(audit);
```

... then this won't work. The new product ID won't be assigned until it is saved and you will get an index violation when it tries to save Product ID 0. Instead you need to provide the audit with a navigation property to the reference of the product that was added to the order:

```
var audit = new Audit 
{
   // .. populate values from this order..
   Product = product // Reference the related, now tracked entity, not the PK
}
AuditEvents.Add(audit);
```

This way when the `DbContext` goes to save the Order, Product, and Audit Event to the database it knows how these entities and their underlying FKs are associated, and will fill them in accordingly.